# Cannot run .NET Core 3.1 tests projects on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, nunit

I am having trouble running tests from inside VS. I created the simplest solution with just one NUnit Test project from the template and one test with Assert.IsTrue(true).

Here are the NuGet packages I added to the project with their versions in case it helps:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.8.0
- NUnit 3.12.0
- NUnit3TestAdapter 3.17.0

Here is the output I get when running the tests from the command line using dotnet test [projName]:

```
Determining projects to restore...
Restored /Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/Test.csproj (in 331 ms).
  Test -> /Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.dll
Test run for /Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.8.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: 29 ms - /Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.dll (netcoreapp3.1)
```

But whenever I try to run them from VS for mac I get the following behaviour:

1. The tests names don't show up in the panel
2. The test run doesn't finish
3. I get the following error in the output:

```
Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:778 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2006 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.ProcessHelper.LaunchProcess (System.String processPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVariables, System.Action`2[T1,T2] errorCallback, System.Action`1[T] exitCallBack) [0x00101] in <06d9ef76610d4473ae17230fef5fa07d>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0006d] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchTestHostAsync (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00096] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:496 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:466 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sources) [0x00115] in <c4016cc04b6c4d6fb0610501f99366ce>:0 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:778 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2006 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.ProcessHelper.LaunchProcess (System.String processPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVariables, System.Action`2[T1,T2] errorCallback, System.Action`1[T] exitCallBack) [0x00101] in <06d9ef76610d4473ae17230fef5fa07d>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0006d] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchTestHostAsync (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00096] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 <---

Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:778 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2006 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.ProcessHelper.LaunchProcess (System.String processPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVariables, System.Action`2[T1,T2] errorCallback, System.Action`1[T] exitCallBack) [0x00101] in <06d9ef76610d4473ae17230fef5fa07d>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0006d] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchTestHostAsync (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00096] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:496 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:466 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sources) [0x00115] in <c4016cc04b6c4d6fb0610501f99366ce>:0 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/dotnet', CommandLine='exec --runtimeconfig "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.deps.json" "/Users/OpenMinder/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.8.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll" --port 56039 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:056039 --role client --parentprocessid 8638 --telemetryoptedin false', CurrentDirectory='/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:778 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2006 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.ProcessHelper.LaunchProcess (System.String processPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVariables, System.Action`2[T1,T2] errorCallback, System.Action`1[T] exitCallBack) [0x00101] in <06d9ef76610d4473ae17230fef5fa07d>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchHost (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0006d] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<LaunchTestHostAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.LaunchTestHostAsync (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestProcessStartInfo testHostStartInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00096] in <8b213d9f519447a3ad29e7a4013d8bc9>:0 <---
```

VS version 8.8 build 2913

macOS Catalina 10.15.7

My current dotnet info:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.404 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Anybody has any idea of what else I can try?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: At terminal, what does `dotnet test` tell you?

Comment: Hi @LexLi I have added the result of dotnet test to the description. It looks pretty normal to me. I know I could always run the tests this way, but I need a VS IDE for a project I am starting and I am pretty sure at some point I will need to debug tests.

Comment: Comparing the two indicates that `dotnet test` only detects `/Users/OpenMinder/DevTraining/Test` as a test project, while VS for Mac detects `/Users/OpenMinder/Dev training/eco-bonus/Api/Api.UnitTests` as a test project. You might dig further to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @LexLi good spot, but that was my mistake. The output was from my real project but the dotnet test result was from a simpler version. I updated the output log to match the simpler solution now. 

Something that seems suspicious is that in the output log it is looking for the netcoreapp2.1 version of the microsoft.testplatform.testhost package and the project is in .NET Core 3.1 (I don't have a netcoreapp3.1 folder for this package even with the 16.8.0 which is the latest stable version).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone, I managed to solve this now, I created a symbolic link in the past to fix something else and I forgot about that.

I fixed this by removing that link with this command:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

Now I am able to use both VS Code and VS for Mac.

Thanks!